# How to Filter collection based on multiple store view ids?

Tags: magento2, collection, filter

My custom model collection has a database table that contains store_ids value separated by comma like this:

```
ID | store_ids  |
+++++++++++++++++
 1 |  0,1,3     |
 2 |  1         |
 3 |  0,1       |
 4 |  0,2       |
 5 |  3         |
```

I'm using this input field to save the store_ids in the backend:

[image]

i noticed the `0` value is the default value , and the rest is the specific store ids value. My question is , how can i retrieve by the current store id, and prioritize the record that has the single store id value, for example with store_id  = `1` it will retrieve the record with ID `2` ?

i tried this, but this filter can not give the specific store_id as first priority :

```
     ->addFieldToFilter(
              'visible_stores',
              [
                  [
                      array('like' => '%'.$this->getStoreId().'%')
                  ],
                  [
                      array('like' => '%0%')
                  ]
              ]
          );
```

Comment: Can you please upload your code what you have tried?

Comment: @RohanHapani done

Comment: which code you are using to show the store list in admin configuration?

Answer (score 1):

```
->addFieldToFilter(
              'visible_stores',
              [
                  [
                      array('finset' => $this->getStoreId())
                  ],
                  [
                      array('like' => '%0%')
                  ]
              ]
          );
```